# Regulars Expression Python / Expresiones regulares en Python

Tags: python, string, regex, substring

Necesito extraer una parte de una cadena de caracteres en Python.

En concreto, de esta cadena:

```
'{"movesRemaining":0,"objectivesRemaining":["0","1"],"autoMatches":10,"hintsAppeared":1,"numbersEGPUsed":1,"boostersUsed":{"Ingame-Hammer":0,"Ingame-Cross":0,"Ingame-Area":0},"pregameBoostersUsed":{"Pregame-Rocket":0,"Pregame-Bombs":0,"Pregame-Color":0},"totalReshuffles":0}'
```

Necesito extraer el primer entre corchetes después de la palabra objectivesRemaining, en este caso sería extraer: ["0","1"], en este caso no hay más corchetes pero podría haberlos.

Un saludo

Comment: sé que tiene la forma de json, pero yo lo que tengo es una cadena, no puedo tratarlo como json, el tipo es string, alguna forma de volver a convertirlo a json?

Comment: JSON **es** una cadena, solo que su contenido sigue una cierta estructura. Lo único que tienes que hacer es procesar esa cadena con `json.loads()` para convertirlo en una estructura de datos "normal". Mira mi respuesta. Pruébala, y dime si algo no te ha funcionado.

Answer (score 3):

## Con expresiones regulares

**TL;DR: No se puede**

Las expresiones regulares no son la herramienta adecuada para esto, más que nada porque, como has dicho, puedes tener "varios corchetes", que entiendo que quiere decir varios corchetes anidados, en algo como:

```
"objectivesRemaining": [["0", "1"], ["2", "3"]]
```

por ejemplo. En ese caso no es posible capturar coun una expresión regular lo que hay entre el primer `[` y el último `]`, pues eso exigiría "llevar la cuenta" de cuantos corchetes se van abriendo y cerrando para así detectar cuándo se cierra el corchete que se abrió al principio. Una expresión regular no puede hacer eso, al menos no en python (C# tiene la posibilidad de crear grupos de captura con nombre, y de eliminarlos, y con esto se podría crear una solución, pero sería ciertamente compleja).

Puedes pensar en crear una expresión voraz, que detecte desde que se abre el primer corchete, y "trague todo lo que haya" hasta el último corchete de la cadena. Algo así:

```
r"\"objectivesRemaining\":(\[.*\])"
```

Eso funcionaría si efectivamente el último corchete que aparezca en tu cadena fuese el de cierre que buscas (vease [demo en regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6Bpz56/1), pero si tu cadena tiene más adelante otra lista, aparecería un corchete de cierre más adelante, que produciría resultado erróneo, al seguir "tragando" todo hasta ese otro corchete (véase [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Bpz56/2))

Debido a que la cadena que quieres detectar depende de una estructura recursiva (mismo número de corchetes de cierre que de apertura) una regexp Python normal (usando el paquete `re`) no puede hacerlo, ya que este paquete no soporta [expresiones regulares recursivas](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced).

Si hacerlo con expresiones regulares fuese una *absoluta necesidad* (no lo creo), puedes instalar el paquete no estándar, [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)), que sí soporta expresiones regulares recursivas, y usarlas en la forma siguiente:

```
import regex

cadena = '{"movesRemaining":0,"objectivesRemaining":["0","1"],"autoMatches":10,"hintsAppeared":1,"numbersEGPUsed":1,"boostersUsed":{"Ingame-Hammer":0,"Ingame-Cross":0,"Ingame-Area":0},"pregameBoostersUsed":{"Pregame-Rocket":0,"Pregame-Bombs":0,"Pregame-Color":0},"totalReshuffles":0}'

expresion_regular = r'"objectivesRemaining":\s*(\[(?>[^[\]]+|(?R)*)\])'
encontrado = regex.findall(expresion_regular, cadena)
print(encontrado[0])
```

```
["0","1"]
```

Pero en este caso hay otra forma mucho más adecuada.

## Sin expresiones regulares

La cadena suministrada en realidad sigue el formato JSON, y python ya tiene un módulo especifico para extraer la información de este tipo de cadenas. Basta hacer:

```
import json

cadena = '{"movesRemaining":0,"objectivesRemaining":["0","1"],"autoMatches":10,"hintsAppeared":1,"numbersEGPUsed":1,"boostersUsed":{"Ingame-Hammer":0,"Ingame-Cross":0,"Ingame-Area":0},"pregameBoostersUsed":{"Pregame-Rocket":0,"Pregame-Bombs":0,"Pregame-Color":0},"totalReshuffles":0}'

datos = json.loads(cadena)
```

y Python te deja en `datos` un diccionario, equivalente a la estructura de datos contenida en el JSON. En ese diccionario puedes acceder ya usando sintaxis python "normal" para extraer la clave que te interesa, en este caso `"objectivesRemaining"`. Por ejemplo:

```
objetivos = data["objectivesRemaining"]
```

La variable `objetivos` que así obtienes es en este caso una lista (`['0', '1']`), por lo que podrías iterar sobre ella con algo como `for objetivo in objetivos:`, etc.

Pero si no necesitas iterar sino tenerla como cadena (por ejemplo porque vas a volcarla en disco o enviarla por un socket), puedes hacer `str(objetivos)`, lo que te daría la cadena `"['0', '1']"`, o bien volver a convertirla en JSON mediante `json.dumps(objetivos)` que generará la cadena `'["0", "1"]'`, válida para enviar a otra aplicación que espere JSON.