# Crear columna dataframe a partir de otra

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

necesito crear una columna dataframe según los valores de otra.

Dataframe:

```
Ocurrences  level         movesRemaining
0   16      Level_0019    ["0","1"]
1   594     Level_0022    ["4","1"]
2   1109    Level_0023    ["5","2"]
3   300     Level_0024    ["0","3"]
4   9       Level_0028    ["2","4"]
```

Necesito crear una columnan moves1 y otra columna moves2 donde en una entre el primer número de la tupla y en otra el segundo. Decir que no es una lista lo que hay ahí, es decir, es tipo string, así me han llegado los datos.

Si hay alguna manera de pasarlo todo a lista entonces ya podría acceder facilmente.

Un saludo

Comment: A ver, sospecho que esta pregunta está relacionada con [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/296376/7123), también tuya, y si utilizaras la biblioteca `json` para procesar la cadena de entrada y extraer la lista en cuestión, tal como se aconseja en la respuesta, en esa columna una lista en lugar de una cadena. Por otro lado ¿has llegado a probar lo que se indica en esa otra respuesta?

Comment: Lo he probado y no había manera sencilla de convertir todas las lineas del dataframe, unos 6 millones a json, o al menos yo no lo he conseguido, lo que is he conseguido es tener los datos de esta manera en la que creo será más sencillo conseguirlo.

Comment: Acabo de poner una respuesta a esta pregunta, pero aún me gustaría saber por qué no te sirvió lo del json para la otra pregunta, o cómo lo resolviste finalmente (supongo que sin usar expresiones regulares).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero sería convertir los elementos la columna `movesRemaining` en listas python, en vez de cadenas de caracteres. Puedes tratar de hacerlo "a mano", quitando los corchetes que tienen alrededor, usando `str.split()` para partir por la coma, etc. Pero ¿por qué complicarse cuando `json.loads()` puede hacer lo mismo de forma mucho más robusta? Así:

```
import json

df.movesRemaining = df.movesRemaining.apply(json.loads)
```

Tras esto, los elementos de esa columna ya son listas python "de verdad". Ahora, separarlo en otras dos columnas puede hacerse de muchas formas. Una de ellas:

```
df["moves1"], df["moves2"] = zip(*df.movesRemaining)
```

con el resultado:

```
    Ocurrences       level movesRemaining moves1 moves2
 0          16  Level_0019         [0, 1]      0      1
 1         594  Level_0022         [4, 1]      4      1
 2        1109  Level_0023         [5, 2]      5      2
 3         300  Level_0024         [0, 3]      0      3
 4           9  Level_0028         [2, 4]      2      4
```

## Edición

En un comentario el usuario indica que algunas de las listas podrían tener tres elementos, y algunas otras sólo uno, y que en estos casos necesitaría desempaquetarlos en tres columnas o sólo una, respectivamente.

Naturalmente, la tabla no puede tener mayor o menor número de columnas en cada fila. Si al menos un elemento de `movesRemainig` es una lista de tres, habrá que desempaquetar en una tercera columna, y todas las filas que sólo tengan dos elementos en la lista tendrán `None` en esta tercera columna. Y si alguna fila sólo tiene un elemento en la lista, ese elemento irá a la columna `moves1`, mientras que en las columnas `moves2` y `moves3` habrá `None`.

Si este comportamiento te vale, la solución es usar `zip_longest()` en lugar de `zip()`.

Pongamos un ejemplo. Este es el dataframe:

```
    Ocurrences       level movesRemaining
 0          16  Level_0019      ["0","1"]
 1         594  Level_0022      ["4","1"]
 2        1109  Level_0023      ["5","2"]
 3         300  Level_0024  ["0","3","5"]
 4           9  Level_0028      ["2","4"]
 5          50  Level_0029          ["4"]
```

Este es el código que sugiero:

```
import json
from itertools import zip_longest

df["movesRemaining"] = df["movesRemaining"].apply(json.loads)
df["moves1"], df["moves2"], df["moves3"] = zip_longest(*df["movesRemaining"])
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
    Ocurrences       level movesRemaining moves1 moves2 moves3
 0          16  Level_0019         [0, 1]      0      1   None
 1         594  Level_0022         [4, 1]      4      1   None
 2        1109  Level_0023         [5, 2]      5      2   None
 3         300  Level_0024      [0, 3, 5]      0      3      5
 4           9  Level_0028         [2, 4]      2      4   None
 5          50  Level_0029            [4]      4   None   None
```

Si en vez de `None` quieres cualquier otro valor, puedes especificarlo en el parámetro `fillvalue`  de `zip_longest()`. Por ejemplo:

```
df["moves1"], df["moves2"], df["moves3"] = zip_longest(*df["movesRemaining"], fillvalue="-")
```

produce

```
    Ocurrences       level movesRemaining moves1 moves2 moves3
 0          16  Level_0019         [0, 1]      0      1      -
 1         594  Level_0022         [4, 1]      4      1      -
 2        1109  Level_0023         [5, 2]      5      2      -
 3         300  Level_0024      [0, 3, 5]      0      3      5
 4           9  Level_0028         [2, 4]      2      4      -
 5          50  Level_0029            [4]      4      -      -
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pruebo y te digo si me funcionó.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, en cuanto a la forma de mapear los datos en las nuevas columnas, tengo un problema, a veces tengo el formato [0, 1] pero otras veces en esa ahora lista solo hay un número o tres, de la forma [8] o [1, 2, 3], en cual caso tendría que rellenar tres columnas o solo la primera.

Comment: @Franciscovilches He editado la respuesta para añadir cómo manejar ese caso

Comment: Me da este error cuando intento tu solución, gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda, df["obj1"], df["obj2"], df["obj3"] = zip_longest(*df["movesRemaining"], fillvalue="")

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: Pues eso es que no tienes una lista con tres elementos en ninguna de tus filas (en la columna `movesRemaining`) Puedes mirar qué longitud máxima tienen tus listas con `df.movesRemaining.map(len).max()`

Comment: jaja tienes razón, porque estaba probando con una parte solo de los datos, ya que te tengo por aquí te lanzo otra pregunta, para rellenar una columna con un substring de otra, por ejemplo en una tengo Nombre_Juan y quiero meter en otra solo a partir de Juan, como podría hacerlo, muchas gracias, hasta ahora hacía estas operaciones con la funcion iterrows pero no es nada eficiente.

Comment: Mejor abres otra pregunta para esto, y explicas un poco mejor el critero por el que defines "substring" ¿Se trata de coger lo que hay a partir del carácter de índice 6? ¿O de lo que hay a partir del `_`? ¿Es un patrón regular, idéntico para todos los elementos de la columna que quieres separar? Ah, y ya de paso acepta alguna respuesta si es que te sirven :-)

Comment: Sorry, soy nuevo por aquí, me refería a que tengo una columna de tipo string y quiero un substring a partir del quinto caracter pasarlo a otra columna, graciassss

Comment: con `df.nombre_columna.str[5:]` debería funcionar. Si no, crea otra pregunta con más detalles para que me pueda yo también explayar más en la respuesta si es necesario.

Comment: Me fue perfecto, muchas gracias, saludosss